# how to obtain this mobius transformation?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

The Möbius transformations $f\left( z \right) = \frac{{\frac{1}{2}\left( {{k_u} - {k_l}} \right)z}}{{\frac{1}{2}\left( {{k_u} + {k_l}} \right)z + 1}}$ bijectively maps the circle that is symmetric about the real axis and cuts it (real axis) through the points $-1/k_u$
and $-1/k_l$ onto the unit circle. We also have that the real numbers $k_u, k_l$ satisfy $k_u>k_l\ge 0$.

I am trying to understand how it was derived.

Attempts:
I thought about considering the original circle which is centered at $z_0=\frac{-1}{k_u}-R$ with radius $R=\frac{k_u-k_l}{2k_uk_l}$ and performing translation and then scaling it, which gives the function $f(z)=\frac{z-z_0}{R}$ but this does not give the above formula.

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Mobius transformations are transitive on circles in the complex plane, and it takes three points to uniquely determine a circle. Therefore, to find a Mobius transformation that sends a given circle to another, try finding a Mobius transformation that sends three distinct points on one circle to three distinct points on the other. Thinking about the center of the circle isn't always helpful since the stabilizer of a given circle contains a Mobius transformation that sends the center to any given point not lying on the circle already.

Comment: $f$ maps complex conjugates to complex conjugates, therefore the image is the circle which is symmetric wrt the real line and which goes through the points $f(-1/k_u)$ and $f(-1/k_l)$. Also note that the interior of the original circle is not mapped to the unit disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The inversion $\,f_1(z) = \frac{1}{z}\,$ transforms the original circle into another circle $\,\Gamma\,$ of radius $\,\rho = \frac{1}{2}(k_u - k_l)\,$ and center $\,\omega=-\frac{1}{2}(k_u+k_l)\,$.
- The transformation $\,f_2(z)= \frac{1}{\rho}(z-\omega)\,$ transforms $\,\Gamma\,$ to the unit circle.
- The inversion $\,f_3(z)=\frac{1}{z}\,$ transforms the unit circle into itself.

It is easy to verify that $\,\frac{1}{f(z)}= \frac{1}{\rho}\left(\frac{1}{z}-\omega\right)\,$, so $\,f(z)=(f_3 \circ f_2 \circ f_1)(z)\,$ is the composition of the three transformations above, and therefore maps the original circle to the unit circle.

Comment: why do you need to map the unit circle to itself? isn't enough to do the first two transformations?

Comment: how did you exactly know that $f_1(z)$ does what it does?

Comment: @user830472 The inversion $1/z$ transforms circles that do not pass through the origin to non-degenerate circles, and it maps $\{-1/k_u, -1/k_l\} \mapsto \{-k_u, -k_l\}$, so $\{-k_u, -k_l\}$ is a diameter of $\Gamma$. The "*why* $f_3$" question cannot be answered without knowing the context/purpose of this whole transformation, but it has probably something to do with remapping the unit disk to the *exterior* of the unit circle.